# ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found on import tensorflow on RHEL 6.9 (Santiago)

Tags: linux, tensorflow, importerror, glibc, rhel6

I had installed tensorflow on RHEL 6.9 and it is installed successfully. While importing tensorflow ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found is coming. I am trying to install it in non-open internet VM. So if somebody could help in suggesting to resolve it in a non-open internet environment it will be great!!

I expect this error to be removed and GLIBC_2.17 module to be installed and therefore successfully import tensorflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to upgrade to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, or use a Tensorflow port for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.  The Tensorflow build you are trying to use was built against glibc 2.17 (or later), but Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 comes with glibc 2.12, which is quite a bit younger and lacks some functionality.

Comment: Any useful links on how to do that?